# Show another image while showing one image in loop in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to show an image, named **"Result"**, And if a person clicks on the image then, it should show another image, named **"Result image"**, but after clicking, the image **Result** which has to be live input from webcam freezes. Can anyone help me with this ?

Here is my code :

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def showImage(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == 1:
        cv2.imshow('Result Image', img)

cv2.namedWindow('Result')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Result', showImage)


while True:
    _, img = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('Result', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I have tried to set the `waitKey(1)` if the image is clicked in the `if event == 1` statement

Comment: so you want to open a new window called `Result Image` that shows a screenshot while the main window continues streaming the video? is this what you are asking?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Yes I want to do that.

Comment: Add another cv2.waitKey(1)  after the imshow in showImage

Comment: @Micka that dosen't help

Comment: Can you try to manually create the window in advance by calling cv2.namedWindow('Result Image') at the beginning of your program?

Comment: use a proper gui toolkit please. OpenCV is for computer vision, not for making GUIs. -- **DO NOT** call `waitKey()` from event handlers. ONLY call it in the main loop.  -- do you get a traceback? -- your code works for me... perhaps your webcam is broken? (I bypassed the VideoCapture stuff because it shouldn't matter here)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz am I doing it right?

Comment: this, where I replace the VideoCapture stuff, works just fine here: https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/e9ae3a41896bd93faed5cc78b9ec8e09 you the click copies the current frame into the other window. idk what issue you could have. describe it better.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I want to open a new window called `Result Image` that shows a **screenshot of the live camera** or **The frame when the screenshot function was called** while the main window continues streaming the video, but in your solution above, The main video freezes after the click.

Comment: works fine for me. you must have issues you aren't presenting to us. voting to close, issue not reproducible. please try to reproduce your issue on a different computer.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
import cv2

def showImage(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == 1:

        cv2.imshow('Result Image', img)

cv2.namedWindow('Result')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Result', showImage)
cv2.namedWindow('Result Image')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('Result', img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) != -1: break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Well, I am now looking to hide the image generated first.